# Warning: Error in <Anonymous>: cannot open file 'Rplots.pdf'

Tags: r, pdf, web, shiny

After I deploy my R shiny App in web server, it produced such errors. Can anyone help me to solve it? Thanks.

This error is very weird. I can run it in Shiny web server (http://www.shinyapps.io/). But I can not run it on my own web server. I commented out the code which produce pdf. But the error is still existing.

su: ignore --preserve-environment, it's mutually exclusive to --login.

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:37436
Warning: Error in : cannot open file 'Rplots.pdf'
  48:

Execution halted

Comment: You're going to need to simplify your app to something that still reproduces the error and post it here if you want any help.

Comment: Thanks. user2554330. I find the solution now. I used palette() function in ui.R. When I remove it, it works. I referred this link : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/shiny-discuss/rplot%7Csort:date/shiny-discuss/gWuY9OY6RIs/aFsRHyGFKywJ

Answer (score 2):

When generating plots on Shiny server, it automatically tries to create a PDF file.
You can remove this functionality by having the below in your code, before the plotting function.

```
pdf(file = NULL)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code solves my problem:

```
chown -R shiny:shiny /srv/shiny-server
```

Comment: Easily solved the issue. Had to run it by using sudo privileges.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because your code has a function that generates a plot, and the server is, by default, trying to save it to a pdf file because it's a non-interactive session (that is, it does not display it on the screen).

The fix is to find that statement and remove it.